# popToRootViewController not working when preferLargeTitle is enabled in iOS 11

Tags: swift, ios11, swift4

This code below is working when i'm not using preferLargeTitles. Is this a bug in iOS 11? Any ideas?

This is my code on applying largeTitles and i'm running iOS 11 in a rootViewController:

```
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
                navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
   }
```

And this is my code where I disable the preferLargeTitle in second stack of navigationController:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            // Keep small title. If I uncomment this code, popToRootViewController will work. I just want to have a large title at the rootViewController.
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
}
```

At the end of the navigation stack... I call this code below and it's not working.

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Please read code comments. Thanks!

Comment: Is `self.navigationController` a non-nil value?

Comment: yes, its not nil... here is the stack: 
▿ Optional<UIViewController>
  ▿ some : <Project.ViewController: 0x10408a200>

Comment: What does "it's not working" even mean???? Describe precisely what happens and what you expect. Provide enough code to enable anyone at all to reproduce the problem.

Comment: _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) doesnt work if I used this code: navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that this is not related with the iOS 11 issue. This is because I'm using another library for keyboard avoiding which is has an issue with iOS 11.